# How to use relative position in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

It takes the position where it's lined up, but I want all in the center over each other to use relative position

[Question and pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roXCv.png)

I think I understood relative position, but they are one after another so the relative position is not really the center:

```
<div class="postest">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values) means *relative to its position if it were `static`-ally positioned*. Other than that, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: If you're after allowing elements to overlap easier, I think you'll want to add relative positioning to the `postest` element, and absolute positioning to your `square` elements. The CSS in the attached screenshot is also trying to select any Nth element, not just the squares itself. Try `nth-of-type` instead. I can write more if it sounds like I'm on the right track, but a bit more clarity in your question about what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position, and they are on each other by default, so you don`t need to set its height one-by-one.

```css
.square{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border:solid 1px blue;
            position: relative;
            left:50%;
            top:20%;
        }
        .postest{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
<div class="postest">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```